# How to run django celery with SQS?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

Hello I need to run django celery in production with SQS, but It don't work. I have in my settings these configurations:

```
BROKER_URL = 'sqs://' + AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + ':' + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY + '@'
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqs'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'us-east-1',
    'visibility_timeout': 3600,
    # 'polling_interval': 0.3,
    # 'queue_name_prefix': 'celery-',
}
BROKER_USER = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
BROKER_PASSWORD = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'mall4g-sqs'
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: {
        'exchange': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
        'binding_key': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
    }
}
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'orders-expired-task': {
        'task': 'orders.tasks.orders_expired',
        'schedule': timedelta(hours=2)
    },
    'remember-set-card': {
        'task': 'orders.tasks.remember_set_credit_card',
        'schedule': timedelta(days=14)
    },
    'example': {
        'task': 'orders.tasks.example',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=5)
    },

}
# needed for worker monitoring
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = True
# where to store periodic tasks (needed for scheduler)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

I don't know what else add or what other thing do to make run the djcelery tasks. Please help.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Celery 4.0.0 and have this line

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Namespace tells that all Celery related settings should start with CELERY

Use then CELERY_BROKER_URL, CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to link up Celery and SQS.

In my settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'region': 'eu-west-1',
                            'visibility_timeout': 43200,# in seconds
                            'polling_interval': 3,
                            'queue_name_prefix':'repricer-stage-',
                            'CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS': True
                            }
```

Above, note BROKER_RUL = 'sqs://':

> The login credentials can also be set using the environment variables
>   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, in that case the broker
>   url may only be sqs://.

[source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html).

Be aware that you need a worker active to interact with SQS. Via the console (in your virtual environment):

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info
```

[source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process)